# Trying to remove and add class to single event element breaks scrolling and rainbow color function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, gsap

The offending code block

```
function changeEventDetails(event) {
var src = 'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1'
var locationURI = encodeURI(event.location)
// window.history.state.eventOpen = true
// var currState = window.history.state
// window.history.pushState(currState, null, "")
$('.calEvent .rainbow').text(event.title)
$('#eventID').text(event._id)
$("#startTime").html(moment(event.start).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
$("#endTime").html(moment(event.end).format('MMM Do h:mm A'));
if (event.location == null) {
  $('#location').html("N/A")
} else {
  $('#location').html(event.location)
}
if (event.description == null) {
  $("#eventInfo").html("N/A")
} else {
  $("#eventInfo").html(event.description);
}

$("#eventLink").attr('href', event.url);
// $('#mapContainer').html('<iframe \
//       frameborder = "0" \
//       style = "border:0" \
//       src = ' + src + '&query=' + locationURI + ' \
//       allowfullscreen> \
//       </iframe>')
$('#viewMapLink').attr('href', src + '&query=' + locationURI)
// $('.fc-content:contains('+event.title+')')[0].scrollIntoView(true, {
//   behavior: 'smooth',
//   block: 'start'
// })

TweenMax.to($('#Calendar'), .5, {
  scrollTo: {
    y: $('.fc-content:contains(' + event.title + ')')[0],
    // offsetY: 50
  }
})

if($('.rainbow2').length >= 1 ){
  $('.rainbow2').removeClass()
  $('.fc-content:contains('+event.title+')').addClass('rainbow2')
} else {
  $('.fc-content:contains('+event.title+')').addClass('rainbow2')
}
console.log(event.title)

}
```

The block in particular which is breaking is `if('.rainbow2')` part. When its removed everything works fine. When it is added the ScrollTo function from gsap breaks and the rainbow background upon the selected element disappears completely.

https://github.com/maxcr/testytest

I hosted a github repo but you're going to need dugway to run it

`https://github.com/bigcartel/dugway`

once installed create fresh dugway project. cd into dir and clone my project to overwrite any files with the same name. Then `dugway server` and in another terminal cd into source and `npm run watchProd`

Comment: `$('.rainbow2').removeClass()` will remove *all* classes from the selected elements, not just the `rainbow2` class. Is this desired behaviour?

Comment: Yes i guess @peeebeee is right. try removing the only class instead $('.rainbow2').removeClass('rainbow2')

Comment: Yeah I figured it would be easier to remove all the instances and then re-add it to the desired one than to keep record of the previously added instance, remove that, and then add to the new instance if that makes any sense? I also tried it both ways and it still breaks unfortunately.

Oh wait. Calling removeClass without args removes ALL the classes? That may be my fuck up. I love you guys.

I thought it took the selector as the arg. That was definitely my fuck up.

Comment: Somebody post that as the answer so I can give you sweet sweet kharma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.rainbow2').removeClass()` will remove *all* classes from the selected elements. To just remove the `rainbow2` class you need

`$('.rainbow2').removeClass('rainbow2')`